# How to calculate new value based on sum of duplicate nominal values in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2

I have two columns of data: one for a variable and one for the area that variable occurs in.

```
 veg_dominant  Shape_Area
        Hm1.1   28216.344
  Bp1.2molcae   6509.464
  Bp1.2molcae   43518.162
        Hm1.1   21348.608
        Hm1.1   14529.108
        Hm1.1   18050.676
```

I want to take the sum of the `Shape_Area` for all `veg_dominant` that are the same. 
For example, behind every Hm1.1 i want the sum of all the shape area's that are `Bp1.2molcae`, which would be  50027.626. So i want this number to appear behind both rows that contain `Bp1.2molcae`. The same goes for `Hm1.1`. A new dataframe with just every unique variable and the sum of the `Shape_Area` is what i want to go for in the end.

Expected output for the example above would be:

```
Veg_dominant      Shape_Area
Hm1.1             82144.736
Bp1.2molcae       50027.626
```

I have a lot of rows, but below is the code for just the head as shown in the example above.

```
structure(list(veg_dominant = structure(c(59L, 14L, 14L, 59L, 
59L, 59L), .Label = c("", "Bb1.1.1", "bebouwing", "Beuk", "bos", 
"Bp", "Bp1.1", "Bp1.1.1", "Bp1.1.3", "Bp1.1.3loof", "Bp1.1Calluna", 
"Bp1.2", "Bp1.2desflex", "Bp1.2molcae", "Bp1.3", "Bq11.1", "Bq3.2.5", 
"Bq4.1betpin", "Bq4.1querob", "Bq5.2pinbet", "Bq6.1desflex", 
"Bq6.1molcae", "Bq6.2", "Bq6.2molcae", "Bq9", "Bq99.1", "Bq99.2", 
"Bq99.3", "Dd1", "Dd2.1", "Dd2.2", "Dd3", "Dd5.1", "E00", "G01a", 
"G02", "G03", "G04", "G05", "G06", "G07", "Gc04", "Gc1", "Gc2", 
"Gc3", "Gc4", "grasland", "Grasland ", "H01", "H03", "Hc1", "Hc2", 
"Hc3", "Hc3_0", "Hc3_3", "Hc3Cp", "Hc3t", "hm1.1", "Hm1.1", "Hm1.1_3", 
"Hm1.2", "Hp1.1", "Hpc", "Hv", "jeneverbesstruweel", "Oefendorp", 
"open zand", "Open zand", "opslag", "Opslag", "P02", "Sj1.1", 
"weg", "x", "x00", "X00"), class = "factor"), Shape_Area = c(28216.3437, 
6509.46415, 43518.16186, 21348.60848, 14529.10796, 18050.6759
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we can just do a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)   
df1 %>% 
  group_by(veg_dominant) %>%
  summarise(Shape_Area = sum(Shape_Area))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
aggregate(Shape_Area ~ veg_dominant, df1, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not seem to work. 
The maximum value of the new dataframe for day Hm1.1, is different from the sum of the Shape_Area values from the initial dataframe for Hm1.1. 

I tried this on my large dataset.

Comment: @Stevestingray  If you can update your post with the expected output, that would be great

Comment: I was struggling with this all day, thanks a lot for the solution akrun. Babysteps :).